# MySQL Query with Inner Joins Returning Empty Set

Tags: mysql, sql, database, inner-join

This has really been bugging me for a while. I'm trying to write an SQL query to return all courses (names), their instructors (names),and their prerequisite course (if they exist). But my query just isn't working and I don't know what to do anymore. I keep getting an empty set returned.

```
SELECT course, instructors.inst, 
something 
FROM courses a inner join instructors ON a.course_id = instructors.inst_id
INNER JOIN courses b ON a.prereq = b.course_id where a.prereq IS NOT NULL;
```

Am I doing something wrong with the multiple inner joins? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Perhaps there are no courses which satisfy all the criteria?

Comment: Also, it's amazingly unlikely that an instruct_id would reference  a course_id

Comment: It would be helpful, if you post definition of related tables ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

LEFT OUTER JOIN should give You the result.Inner join will return results only in case you have data in all of the joined tables.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
SELECT a.course_name AS "Course", instructors.inst_name AS "Instructor", 
b.course_name AS "Prereq"
FROM courses a
LEFT OUTER JOIN instructors ON a.course_id = instructors.inst_id
LEFT OUTER JOIN courses b ON a.prereq = b.course_id
```